# Portfolio permalink wont change with rewrite command, how do I change it?

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

Using the plugin `Virtue-toolkit > post-types.php` I have attempted to change the permalink of a portfolio.

I then changed line 27 to the following:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'game-server' ), /* you can specify its url slug */
```

According to available documentation this should work. I'm just trying to change the slug from 'portfolio' to 'game-server', but it's not updating.

I have even gone to `settings > permalinks` and selected to flush on save, but still no luck.

The code is [here](http://pastebin.com/6tNSgNyX).

Answer (score 0):

I have check your code and review it. I have suggestion for you. To rewrite url you need to use `.htaccess` and add some `rewrite` rule in your `.htaccess` file.